# Cant select the window i want to sent keyboard inputs

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, dosbox

I try to get a window active to send keyboard inputs using

```
[DllImport("USER32.DLL", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

[DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IntPtr calcWindow = FindWindow(null, "Calculator");

    if (SetForegroundWindow(calcWindow))
        SendKeys.Send("10{+}10=");
}
```

I am new to c# and i saw i need to put the exact name that apears on the taskbar, but i try to sent keyboard events to DOSBox which [the name of the window i want to select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Le1r2.png) has a weird name that i tried to write multiple times but i didnt get the right thing, do you know how i can browse the windows already opened and select this one or how can i get the exact name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `System.Diagnostics.Process` to find the process. You can find the process by its `ProcessName` and then get its `MainWindowHandle`.

```
[DllImport("USER32.DLL", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

[DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // find the process by its name, this is the process name and is not the window name
    System.Diagnostics.Process process = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses()
        .FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProcessName.Equals("DOSBox"));
            
    if(process != null)
    {
        IntPtr calcWindow = process.MainWindowHandle;
        SetForegroundWindow(calcWindow);
        if (SetForegroundWindow(calcWindow))
            SendKeys.SendWait("10{+}10=");
    }           
}
```